# allow access for specific IP addresses on jboss 7.1

Tags: security, jboss7.x, ip-address

I have `Jboss 7.1 AS`. I want to allow only specific IP addresses to access this Jboss.(If my IP is 172.7.7.7 , only allowed ips should be able to access 127.7.7.7:8080)

Does anyone know where and how should I configure this?